# I created a JButton that plays a sound when clicked - How do I implement that on more buttons

Tags: java

```
package pkgnew;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

public class bob
{
JButton test = new JButton("");
JButton test1 = new JButton("");
JButton test2 = new JButton("");
JButton test3 = new JButton("");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public void playSound(String soundName)
 {
   try 
   {
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile());
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
     ex.printStackTrace( );
   }
 }    

 public bob() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Movie Stars");
    test.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Leonardo.jpg"));
    test1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Bruce.jpg"));
    test2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Jim.jpg"));
    test3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bob\\Desktop\\Robert.jpg"));

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(1000, 800);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    panel.add(test);
    panel.add(test1);
    panel.add(test2);
    panel.add(test3);

    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));

    test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
         playSound("Leonardo.wav");

        }  
    }
  );
}  

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    bob t = new bob();
} 
}
```

So basically I have a grid with 4 buttons of pictures, and I'm trying to make it so when you click each picture a sound plays. I implemented it for one of the buttons however everything I have tried so far to make it work for the other 3 buttons has not been successful. I thought I would just duplicate the `test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {` and replace 'test' with 'test1' but that's not it I also tried to add an 'else if catch' to that play loop so that if `e.getSource() == test` then it would play one of the sounds, `else if e.getSource() == test2` it would play another but did not work

Comment: _"has not been successful"_ -- HOW? What happened? What did you do to troubleshoot?

Comment: I tried to do an 'else if' structure to get the other sounds to play when you click on the different picutres.                              `test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if (e.getSource() == test) {
                    try {
             playSound("Leonardo.wav");
            
         }catch(Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
                }
                else if (e.getSource() == test1) {   
                    try {
                        playSound("Jim.wav");`

Comment: @archer Is there any exception or error you are seeing?

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq No it runs normally and plays the first sound file for the first picture if you click it just like the code in the original post does but clicking the other pictures does not play any sound file

Comment: Does it play another sound if you click another button first?

Comment: @user1274820 Nope it does not

Comment: While your code is somehow weird, it works, so you may have problems with the sounds...

Comment: I just downloaded a java compiler to test your code and all 4 buttons work just fine. Might want to check the filepaths of your wav files as Jean-Baptiste Yunes said.

Comment: `test2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { playSound("C:\\Users\\DarkTussin\\Music\\Beep.wav"); }});` Worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, your code works just fine.

I downloaded Netbeans just to check it out for you :p

Here is the code working as intended:

[image]

Here is the ActionListener code I used (tested with 2 different sounds):

```
test.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     playSound("C:\\Users\\DT\\Music\\Beep.wav");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Beep1 Just Went Off");
    }  
});
test1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     playSound("C:\\Users\\DT\\Music\\Beep2.wav");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Beep2 Just Went Off");
    }  
});
test2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     playSound("C:\\Users\\DT\\Music\\Beep.wav");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Beep3 (Beep.wav) Just Went Off");
    }  
});
test3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     playSound("C:\\Users\\DT\\Music\\Beep.wav");
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Beep4 (Beep.wav) Just Went Off");
    }  
});
```

Comment: Okay yeah thank you I apparently somehow implemented the new action listeners incorrectly because it was telling me there was no such thing as 'package test2' so I guess I was doing it one } before the ;

Comment: `Array` is always a better idea for similar type of data rather copy pasting code. isn't?

Answer (score 1):

I did pretty much the same thing and it also works for me. I also made some improvements in the sound loading.

```
package helloworld;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by matt on 4/4/16.
 */
public class PlaySounds {
    Map<String, Clip> sounds = new HashMap<>();
    public PlaySounds(){
        loadResources("A.wav");
        loadResources("B.wav");
    }

    public void loadResources(String soundName){
        try
        {
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(soundName).getAbsoluteFile());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            sounds.put(soundName, clip);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton a = new JButton("A");
        JButton b = new JButton("B");

        PlaySounds sounds = new PlaySounds();

        a.addActionListener(evt->{
            sounds.playSound("A.wav");
        });

        b.addActionListener(evt->{
            sounds.playSound("B.wav");
        });

        panel.add(a, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void playSound(String soundName){
        Clip c = sounds.get(soundName);
        c.setFramePosition(0);
        c.start();
    }
}
```

Instead of loading the sound again each time it is click, I loaded the sounds when I started the program.

To answer your question in the title. I added two action listeners, one to each button that plays the different sounds.